# How mobile Firefox addon can recieve information from it's Desktop version? (if both are logged in)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-android

I want to be able to close tabs on my mobile Firefox, while using Desktop version of Firefox. I thought Tab-sync would make it work, but it doesn't. So now I'm on the quest to fix it with an extension.

I have thought about using sync area of storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/sync) but it's not supported on Android.

Do I have to build some external service to send command from Desktop version to that service and then use Mobile Firefox extension to do the polling or there is a better way to utilize fact that I'm logged on both of these devices.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Yes, sharing information using a server looks like a feasible idea. You can try to use WebSockets to be able to push messages to the mobile Firefox, instead of having to pull all the time.

Comment: sad, this have to be this way, having the fact that they already do sync. Thanks anyway